# How to send Object which contains an arraylist in the postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I am doing a project in springboot rest API.
My controller class look like below,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/artdimfil", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public boolean saveArticleDimFilter(@RequestBody ArtDimFil artDimFil)
```

I want to send the below payload in the postman,

```
{
    "id": "b30d1486-04c8-4acc-8d14-8604c81accab",
    "docIdentifier": {
        "recType": "ABC",
        "accesslist": [
         {
        "userid": "xyz@abc.com",
        "role": "abc",
        "status": "Active",
        "actiondate": "2020-07-03T17:59:34.600+0000",
        "name": "XYZ",
      }]
    }
}
```

But it is giving the error saying

```
[org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.ibm.epm.next.model.Accesslist` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.ibm.epm.next.model.Accesslist` out of START_ARRAY token.
```

Please suggest me what to do.

Comment: please fix json formatting and show also how ArtDimFil looks like

Comment: @a4dev92 : corrected the json formatting.. The ArtDimFil look like this, @JsonProperty("_id")
    private String _id;
    @JsonProperty("docIdentifier")
    private DocIdentifier docIdentifier;
    @JsonProperty("dimfilDocData")
    private DimfilDocData dimfilDocData;

Comment: You have an 'Accesslist' object, but you need an array of objects: List<Access>. This is the correct way to deserialize a Json array

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to deserialize to "AccessList" - but I think it's not using YOUR "AccessList", because the error says:
Cannot deserialize instance of `com.ibm.epm.next.model.Accesslist`

I suggest you rename your class, or make sure you have the correct import statement. You should import your own "AccessList" class.

Comment: Thank you it is working now, but there is another issue now.. I dont see accessList data in eclipse while debugging. 
The data should be there in accessList array right? I dont see it. Do you have any idea?

"userid": "xyz@abc.com",
    "role": "abc",
    "status": "Active",
    "actiondate": "2020-07-03T17:59:34.600+0000",
    "name": "XYZ"

Comment: can you show your "Accesslist" class? List<Accesslist> sounds like List<List>. Not sure if that's a problem.

Comment: AccessList is a setter/getter method.
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "userid",
    "role",
    "status",
    "actiondate",
    "name"
})
public class AccessList{

    @JsonProperty("userid")
    private String userid;
    @JsonProperty("role")
    private String role;
    @JsonProperty("status")
    private String status;
    @JsonProperty("actiondate")
    private String actiondate;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    private String __caseId;

Comment: Hm without further information I cannot help you. But feel free to vote/accept my answer if it solved your initial problem. Ask a new question with details about the list not showing up in eclipse if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should delete comma after "XYZ"

```
   {
    "userid": "xyz@abc.com",
    "role": "abc",
    "status": "Active",
    "actiondate": "2020-07-03T17:59:34.600+0000",
    "name": "XYZ",
  }
```

also will be good show how looks docIdentifier  class and show what class inside accesslist

Comment: That comma is made by mistake. DocIdentifier and Accesslist class are POJO.

Here is DocIdentifier class look, 
@JsonProperty("rec_type")
    private String recType;
    @JsonProperty("accesslist")
    private List<Accesslist> accesslist = new ArrayList<Accesslist>();

And here is how  Accesslist class looks,
 @JsonProperty("userid")
    private String userid;
    @JsonProperty("role")
    private String role;
    @JsonProperty("status")
    private String status;
    @JsonProperty("actiondate")
    private String actiondate;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;